# Round to the nearest half an hour or hour in ruby fake time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I am using fake time to display in my UI. I am manipulating the time to be random like this.

```
  date: Time.zone.now - (i % 9).days - rand(3).days - rand(2).hours + rand(60).minutes
```

However I would like to round to the nearest hour that is 3.35 pm becomes 3.30

do you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can extend the time class with this method 
I normally do this in the lib/core_ext directory

```
# lib/core_ext/time.rb
class Time
  def round_off(seconds = 60)
    Time.at((self.to_f / seconds).round * seconds)
  end
end
```

now you can  do something like

```
time = Time.zone.now - rand(3).days - rand(2).hours + rand(60).minutes
time.round_off(30.minutes)
```

I hope that this is able to help you

Comment: You don't need `self.` in `self.to_f`.

Comment: Thanks I will test my code in one of my projects, but I think that would also be code style